# Separate a column containing escape symbol as delimiter in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a 'Name' column in R which contains names and their assigned ID separated by an escape symbol.

For example:

```
#dput(head(df$columnname))

 structure(c(8L, 410L, 238L, 457L, 34L, 115L), .Label = c("Aaron Gordon\\gordoaa01", 
"Aaron Holiday\\holidaa01", "Abdel Nader\\naderab01", ..., class = "factor")
```

I am trying to use `tidyverse` or the `stringr` as this is what most solutions on here have lead me to.

I have tried a few solutions on here such as:

```
separate(columnname,
           c("First_Name","Second_Name","Last_Name","ID"))
```

and

```
separate(columnname, into = c("Name","ID"), sep = "\\d")
```

as well as

```
stringr::str_subset(df$columnname,"\")
```

My main problem is the " \ " symbol. If I could just remove the id that follows the " \ " symbol I will be happy. 
The separate function worked somewhat well, but some players have middle names or initialed names. By using:

```
separate(columnname, c("First_name", Last_name"))
```

I would fix the ID issue, but then create other issues where a players name would be something like:

```
First_name

P

Last_name

J
```

Again, I just really want to remove anything after the `" \ "`, so anything else after that extra helpful.

Comment: can you update your post with `dput(head(df))` ?

Comment: I've just updated this. Sorry about that.

Comment: `str_split(df$columnname, "\\\\")`

Comment: Thank you @Dij - This is the split I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Alright i'll put it in an answer then so we can close the case

Answer (score 0):

Since `\` is an escape character in `regex` syntax, to match, split at, locate, etc. in `stringr` you need to "escape the escape":

```
str_split(df$columnname, "\\\\")
```

Comment: Thank you - This is just what I needed!